# Completely restore a binary from memory?

Tags: memory, dump, elf

I want to know if it's possible to completely restore the binary running in memory.

This is what I've tried,

First read `/proc/PID/maps`, then dump all relevant sections with gdb (ignore all libraries).

```
grep sleep /proc/1524/maps | awk -F '[- ]' \
     '{print "dump memory sleep." $1 " 0x" $1 " 0x" $2 }'  \
   | gdb -p 1524
```

Then I concatenate all dumps in order:

```
cat sleep.* > sleep-bin
```

But the file is very much different than `/bin/sleep`

It seems like to be relocation table and other uninitialized data, so is it impossible to fix a memory dump? (Make it runnable)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm a windows guy and don't know much about the linux process internals and ELF format, but I hope I can help!

I would say it's definitly possible to do, but not for ALL programs. The OS loader loads all parts of the executable into memory that are within a well defined place in the file. For example some uninstallers store data that is appended to the executable file - this will not be loaded to memory so this will be information you cannot restore just by dumping memory.

Another problem is that the information written by the OS is free to be modified by anything on the system that has the right to do so. No normal program would do something like that though.

The starting point would be to find the ELF headers of your executable module in memory and dump that. It will contain pretty much all the data you need for your task. For example:

- the number of sections and where they are in memory and in the file
- how sections in the file are mapped to sections in virtual memory (they usually have different base addresses and sizes!)
- where the relocation data is

For the relocs you would have to read up on that how the reloc data is stored and processed with the ELF format. Once you know that it should be pretty easy to undo the changes for your dump.